# PHP Arrays - change key name with value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a array pulled from MySQL with the form below:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 0
        [settings_name] => auto_email
        [value] => 1
        [date_added] => 0
        [date_created] => 0
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 0
        [settings_name] => email_hour
        [value] => 17
        [date_added] => 0 [date_created] => 0
    )
)
```

What I am trying to do is to change the array to this form:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 0
        [auto_email] => 1
        [date_added] => 0
        [date_created] => 0
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 0
        [email_hour] => 17
        [date_added] => 0
        [date_created] => 0 )
    )
```

I am trying to acces the 'auto_email' setting directly not by settings_name. 
Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways, depending on if you want to create a new array, or just alter the existing one:

Create new:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $newArray[] = array(
        'id' => $value['id'],
        $value['settings_name'] => $value['value'],
        'date_added' => $value['date_added'],
        'date_created' => $value['date_created']
    );
}
```

Alter existing:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key][$value['settings_name']] = $value['value'];
    unset($array[$key]['settings_name']);
    unset($array[$key]['value']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the command array_flip. From what you say i think you must save the id first to another array

see the manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through the items in the array and create a new array the way you want.

```
$output = array();
foreach ($your_input_array as $v){
    $output[]=array(
                    'id' => $v['id'],
                    $v['settings_name']=>$v['value'], //use the setting name as key here
                    'date_added' => $v['date_added'],
                    'date_created' => $v['date_created']
                    );
}
print_r($output);
```

If you want to just alter the existing array you can use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

```
array_walk($your_input_array, function (&$v){
    $v=array(
            'id' => $v['id'],
            $v['settings_name']=>$v['value'], //use the setting name as key here
            'date_added' => $v['date_added'],
            'date_created' => $v['date_created']
            );
});
print_r($your_input_array);
```

The above works only with PHP 5.3+ as anonymous functions are introduced in PHP 5.3. If you are stuck with version less than PHP 5.3 you can do it without anonymous function.

```
array_walk($your_input_array,'fixarray');
function fixarray(&$v){
    $v=array(
        'id' => $v['id'],
        $v['settings_name']=>$v['value'], //use the setting name as key here
        'date_added' => $v['date_added'],
        'date_created' => $v['date_created']
        );
}
print_r($your_input_array);
```